# Why I am getting this folium module is not callable error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, folium

When I type the following code in pycharm:

```
import webbrowser
import folium

m = folium.map(location=[44, 55], zoom_start=20)
m.save('map2.html')
webbrowser.open('map2.html', new=2)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\abdel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\pythonmap.py", line 4, in <module>
m = folium.map(location=[44, 55], zoom_start=20)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

how do I fix it?

Python 3.9.1
Windows 10
pycharm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `folium.Map` instead of `folium.map`, map with a capital letter.

When you try to use `folium.map`, it refers to the module `map.py`. This is also what the errror message tells us: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`: Python is calling something which is not callable. `folium.Map` on the other hand, refers to the class `Map`.

Full example:

```py
import webbrowser
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[44, 55], zoom_start=20)
m.save('map2.html')
webbrowser.open('map2.html', new=2)
```